# Django-haystack: How to enable highlighting in my setup?

Tags: python, django, django-haystack

I'm currently adding search functionality to my Django application using [django-haystack v2.0.0-beta](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack) and [Whoosh](https://bitbucket.org/mchaput/whoosh/wiki/Home) as the back end. Creating the index and returning the search results works fine so far. Now I want to enable the highlighting feature but I don't get it to work.

I'm using a highly customized setup for which the haystack documentation is not a great help. My Django application is a pure AJAX application, i.e., all requests between client and server are handled asynchronously by using jQuery and `$.ajax()`. That's why I have written a custom Django view that creates the haystack search queryset manually and dumps the search results into a JSON object. All of this works fine, but the addition of highlighting does not work. Here is my code that I have so far:

**search_indexes.py**

```
class CrawledWebpageIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)

    def get_model(self):
        return CrawledWebpage # This is my Django model
```

**forms.py**

```
class HaystackSearchForm(forms.Form):

    q = forms.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        label='Enter your search query')
```

**views.py** (I adopted some code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3037283/1125413) as it looked reasonable to me but it's probably wrong)

```
def return_search_results_ajax(request):
    haystack_search_form = HaystackSearchForm(request.POST)
    response = {}

    if haystack_search_form.is_valid():
        search_query = haystack_search_form.cleaned_data['q']
        sqs = SearchQuerySet().filter(content=search_query)
        highlighted_search_form = HighlightedSearchForm(request.POST, searchqueryset=sqs, load_all=True)
        search_results = highlighted_search_form.search()

        # Here I extract those fields of my model that should be displayed as results
        webpage_urls = [result.object.url for result in search_results[:10]]
        response['webpage_urls'] = webpage_urls

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response), mimetype='application/json')
```

This code works fine as far as the search results are returned properly. But when I try to access the highlighted text snippet for a search result, for example for the first one:

```
print search_results[0].highlighted
```

Then I always get an empty string as the result: `{'text': ['']}`

Can anyone help me to get the highlighting feature working? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Hello again! Which haystack backend are you using?

Comment: @Emily I'm using Whoosh as the backend. I already said that in my original post. I know that Whoosh supports highlighting, so it's not a wrong backend that causes my problem.

Comment: Sorry, missed that in the question.

Comment: It seems you're not the only one with this problem? https://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack/issues/310 https://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack/issues/273 https://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack/issues/582

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this is possibly a Haystack bug that has gone unresolved for a long time: http://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack/issues/310 
http://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack/issues/273 
http://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack/issues/582

As an alternative, you could use Haystack's highlighting functionality instead of Whoosh's to highlight the results yourself. For example, once you get your search results in `sqs`, you could do

```
from haystack.utils import Highlighter
highlighter = Highlighter(search_query)
print highlighter.highlight(sqs[0].text)
```

to get the highlighted text of the first result. See http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/highlighting.html for the documentation.

Comment: Indeed, I should have browsed through the open issues on GitHub first. It's obviously not my fault then. I've just tried out Haystack's highlighting functionality and it works fine. So I will go with that. Again, thanks a lot, Emily! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Haystack but could it be because you're using `HaystackSearchForm` in one place and `HighlightedSearchForm` in another?

Comment: Maybe, but I don't think so at the moment because the search results are returned properly. If you know a way to accomplish the same with `HighlightedSearchForm` only, I'm curious.

Comment: It's the same as `SearchForm` but adds highlighting, read the [HighlightedSearchForm](https://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/views_and_forms.html?highlight=HighlightedSearchForm#highlightedsearchform) docs.

Comment: You don't say. ;) I already did that. If it had helped me, I wouldn't have asked here.

Comment: Actually, Haystack provides forms which your form should inherit from instead of `forms.form`. I imagine you want `HighlightedSearchForm`.