# Django Haystack: Filtering by object properties

Tags: django, django-haystack, django-oscar

I'm trying to build a page that renders searched Oscar products and filters them by their Category using GET attributes. I'm overriding get_queryset and building my object list from there

```
class ProductSearchView(ListView):
    model = Product
    template_name = "productsearch/product_list.html"
    queryset = Product.objects.none()

    def get_queryset(self):
        word_query_attr = self.request.GET.get('q', None)  # word query
        sqs = SearchQuerySet().models(Product).filter(Q(title__icontains=word_query_attr) |
                                                  Q(category__name__icontains=word_query_attr) |
                                                  Q(upc__icontains=word_query_attr) |
                                                  Q(description__icontains=word_query_attr))
        qs = Product.objects.all()

        if self.request.GET.get('cat', None):
            cat_attr = self.request.GET.get('cat', None)
            category = Category.objects.get(name=cat_attr)
            qs = qs.filter(categories__in=category.get_children())
```

My question is, can I use `SearchQuerySet()` to filter through fields from result objects? (in this case, categories from Product objects)

If not, is there an effective way I can create a Product queryset using `SearchQuerySet()` results?
I've tried filtering through IDs

```
object_ids = [result.object.id for result in sqs]
qs = qs.filter(id__in=object_ids).distinct()
```

But there are two problems: it isn't scalable (as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3037283/2879529)) and some queries are very slow when I'm dealing with ~900 results.

Answer (score 2):

I might be missing something, but the `SearchQuerySet` filter in your example is already restricting by category name? Could you just change that filter to `exact` instead of `icontains` and pass your `cat` GET param?

```
sqs = SearchQuerySet().models(Product).filter(
    Q(title__icontains=word_query_attr) |
    Q(upc__icontains=word_query_attr) |
    Q(description__icontains=word_query_attr)
)

cat_attr = self.request.GET.get('cat')
if cat_attr:
    sqs.filter(category__name__exact=cat_attr)
```

I think Haystack should let you chain filters like that.

Comment: Hi! Sorry for the late reply! That makes sense, I don't know how I didn't think of that. Let me test the solution and I'll get right back to you